# Trash talking and unsupportive C-suite boss. Should I leave?

Tags: manager, quitting

A few weeks ago, my boss, who is a direct report to our CEO, sent a negative text about me, to me, accidentally. He did this while I was presenting some unfortunate January revenue results to the CEO on a teleconference. He tried to cover it up by making it as if it were a typo (and blamed someone else instead), but he's always trash talked about others to me, so I was fully aware he probably was always doing the same about me.

I've been fortunate to rise very quickly in my company, and have always received a ton of respect and good feedback from others in the C-suite. But since the incident, they're all treating me differently. Yes, January's performance was poor, but we're poised to have a fantastic year (and we had a phenomenal Q4). I can't imagine one month of poor performance would justify the loss of respect / trust in my ability to lead the team, but that's how I was recently treated at an in-person company meeting.

It's bad, but my boss is in my head, and I can't help but think he's trying to get ahead of his text message mistake by further throwing me under the bus. Should I put my head down and knock 2019 out of the park, leave a really bad boss, or confront him?

Comment: What are your opportunities of changing the manager within the same company?

Answer (score 3):

> Should I put my head down and knock 2019 out of the park, leave a
>   really bad boss, or confront him?

If you have concluded that you have a really bad boss and you don't expect that situation to change for the foreseeable future, then it probably makes sense to look for a new job. The number one reason people leave a job is because of their boss.

On the other hand, if you think you can change this really bad boss into a good one, then confrontation may be the answer.

Finally, if you conclude that this is temporary and could just blow over, then put your head down and knock 2019 out of the park.

You really haven't provided enough information to determine which path is optimal. I suspect that it's quite possible the different treatment you see from the C-suite is temporary. Only you are in a position to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when these things happen, you can then be hypersensitive to interactions with others, looking for a change in behaviour. So you very well be spotting things that are not there.

You are right, one month is one month.

I have a feeling deep down you know the correct course of action is to put your head down and focus on 2019. I would not confront him, or quit based on perceptions.

You should have faith that the other C-levels will eventually see things for what they are.

If not, it sounds like you will have a very positive track record to put on your CV.